# How can I scroll through content and stick at paragraphs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For my website I have a div that is 400px wide by 200px in height. I have a lot of text in this box and it is meant to be scrolled through. I want to set it up so that as I am scrolling down through the div, each paragraph sticks until you scroll far enough for the next one to quickly slide up. I want almost a bounce effect as the new one slides in, such as I was manually scrolling fast, then slow, and then I stopped. How can I code this through CSS3 and HTML5 or JavaScript?

Comment: css/html are markup and styling languages. they are not "programming" languages, and cannot do anything of what you want. this can only be done in JS, basically.

Comment: In response to Marc: CSS3 has had a number of updates recently that encompass this sort of thing, things such as sticky scrolling can now be done through CSS without any JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a great new article (by SARAH DRASNER) with an example of exactly what you are trying to achieve: [**CSS Scroll Snap Points**](https://css-tricks.com/introducing-css-scroll-snap-points/)

The new [CSS Scroll Snap Points spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-snappoints/) is pretty new and not supported in all browsers but you should use a [polyfill](https://github.com/ckrack/scrollsnap-polyfill) to add the necessary support.

The magic happens with this css

```
  -webkit-scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100%);
      -ms-scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100%);
          scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100%);

  -webkit-scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
      -ms-scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
          scroll-snap-type: mandatory;

  -webkit-scroll-snap-destination: 100% 0%;
      -ms-scroll-snap-destination: 100% 0%;
          scroll-snap-destination: 100% 0%;
```

Here is a codepen example of it http://codepen.io/sdras/pen/43c9d13b23bc34a85bb3a5e2ea985958